# Set the Underline length

Tags: javascript, react-native

I would to set the underline length, do you know how can I do?

The length of this underline depends on the word length,  I would set this dimension.

```
View style={consumer.body}>
          <View style={consumer.bodyInputs}>
            <TextInput
              style={consumer.inputs}
              placeholder="Codice Fiscale"
              keyboardType="default"
              underlineColorAndroid="grey"
              onChangeText={value => {
                //code... 
              }
              }
            />
          </View>
```

This is about the style

```
body: {
        alignItems: "center",
        marginTop: 10,
        marginBottom: 10
    },
    bodyInputs:{
        marginTop: 10
    },
    inputs: {
        height: 45,

      },
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy approach is to use an empty `<View />`. See Example below:

```
   <View style={styles.body}>
      <View style={styles.bodyInputs}>
        <TextInput
          style={styles.inputs}
          placeholder="Codice Fiscale"
          keyboardType="default"
          underlineColorAndroid="grey"
        />
        // here we create your bottom border 
        <View style={{width: 80, height: 1, backgroundColor: '#000'}}/>
      </View>
    </View>
```

**Output:**

[image: output]

**Working Snack:**

https://snack.expo.io/Byyvw593r